Como solucionar este error: ImportError: No module named administrador.models
Cuando corro el proyecto me  sale este  error:  "../apps/citas/models.py", line 4, in 
from apps.administrador.models import PersonalTercero
ImportError: No module named administrador.models" ya validé el modulo existe en instaled_apps, y la importacion se está realizando correctamente en el modulo citas. Antes del error eliminé los archivos pyc, no se si tiene que  ver con el problema. Probé reinstalar las dependencias, volver a una rama anterior, y cambiar el entorno virtual, pero nada soluciona el error.

Comparte el código para que te podamos ayudar.
